# How can I add an Automator application to the Dock?

Tags: macos, automator, dock, launchpad

I followed the directions in [How to put a custom launcher in the Dock (Mavericks)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115114/how-to-put-a-custom-launcher-in-the-dock-mavericks) but my case has a different twist. I have an Automator application which runs a shell script that (1) changes the stack size with `ulimit` and (2) runs an application. I would like to add this to the Dock. I can run it from the Launchpad and everything works correctly. It shows up in my Dock, but only as the application, not the Automator version. As a result, if I right click and enable 'Keep in Dock', then close and run again, the stack limit change of (1) is ignored. How do I put an icon in the Dock which runs the Automator application and not just the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag and drop the app_name.app bundle created in Automator onto the Dock where you want it.

Comment: I need to clarify, when I said _"...drag and drop the Automator.app bundle onto the Dock..."_ I didn't mean the actual "/Applications/Automator.app" bundle but the <app_name>.app bundle created in Automator.  I've edited the answer to reflect the comment.

Comment: hrm, i only see a `.action` file, not a `.app` file...  ?

Comment: But it still shows the active indicator under the original app, not the Automator version. This also means that I cannot run both the original app and the Automator version simultaneously.