# Eclipse 'luna' installing issues on MacOs Sierra 10.12

Tags: macos, eclipse

im getting issues while installing eclipse luna for MacOS Sierra 10.12

I have followed the procedure for the installing the eclipse.

1.Download the eclipse luna.
2.move the zipped folder to desktop.
3.extract the zipped file.
4.move eclipse icon from desktop to the applications folder.
5.when I double click the eclipse icon, it gives the following error.

below is the screenshots attached, can anybody help me with the solution.

Error - " Eclipse quit unexpectedly- Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple."

[image]

Comment: This is an error message! The detailed information is hidden behind the Report... button! What do you expect us to do? Exact duplicate of [Eclipse quit unexpectedly \[closed…\]](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98620/eclipse-quit-unexpectedly)

Comment: I got the same problem as you do.
Here is system report: http://pastebin.com/fMsg5XPg

Comment: If someone could edit a specific version of Luna and a specific version of 10.12 into the s might get better answers, especially if it a bug that gets fixed in time.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue for me. The issue resolved when I copied the complete pack into the "Applications" folder and ran Eclipse in the path `/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS` from Terminal.

Comment: This post might be handy to those who would like to turn the absolute path into an app in the Applications folder. Extract your eclipse folder somewhere other than the Applications folder and then create an Automator link to it following the accepted answer in this post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115114/how-to-put-a-custom-launcher-in-the-dock-mavericks